# 360° rotation "feature" in F# bit shift operators

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, bit-shift

The bit shift operators in F# are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469495.aspx) as not doing rotation when you shift bits past the end of the value. You can see this in F# Interactive:

```
> let a = 128uy
- a <<< 1;;

val a : byte = 128uy
val it : byte = 0uy
```

That is, we shifted the high bit off the top of 128, giving 0.

If F# rotated bits rather than shifting them off the end, we would have gotten 1 instead, as the 1 bit in the [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) position would get rotated down to the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit).

However, if you make a small change to the second statement, you get a surprising result:

```
> let a = 128uy
- a <<< 8;;

val a : byte = 128uy
val it : byte = 128uy
```

Now it looks to have done a full rotation of the bits in the byte!

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that F# is doing [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on the value on the right hand side of the bit shift operator before doing the shift. For an unsigned byte, it uses `mod` 8, since there are 8 bits in an F# byte. Since 8 `mod` 8 is 0, it is not shifting the bits in the byte at all.

You can see this more clearly if you play with the values a bit:

```
> let a = 4uy
- a <<< 1;;

val a : byte = 4uy
val it : byte = 8uy

> a <<< 9;;
val it : byte = 8uy
> a <<< 17;;
val it : byte = 8uy
```

We get the same result in all three cases because they are equivalent expressions in `mod` 8.

The same thing happens with right-shift (`>>>`), and the behavior isn't limited to bytes.

Comment: This is explained on this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @JohnPalmer: That page doesn't seem quite on point, to me. First, its about C#, not F#. How does a C# design choice constrain F#? Are you claiming the behavior is actually due to the CLR, not the language compiler? Second, it doesn't talk about rotating byte values at all, only the rules for 32- and 64-bit integer rotations. The only way I can see this being the reason for the F# behavior is that the C# docs neglect this difference because of automatic integer promotion, which doesn't happen in F#.

Comment: Here is the code for the F# implementation of `<<<` for `int32`  `(# "shl" x (mask n 31) : int #)` where mask is `let inline mask (n:int) (m:int) = (# "and" n m : int #)`.  This is exactly identical to the C# operator - and the number with `31` and then shift by some number of bytes.  The implementation for `byte` is identical, except it changes the mask and converts to and from int as .NET does not support bit-shifting bytes

Comment: @JohnPalmer: So, F# is *following* the C# design choice here, not constrained by it or by the CLR. They *could* have made F# behave like C, for example, where `(uint8_t)(n << 8) == 0`.

Comment: Interestingly, if you disassemble the code and change the constants, there is no effect for `int32` (at least on my machine) changing to masking by `0xff` instead of `0x1f` causes identical results, although you can obviously recreate the C style conversions for bytes.  I guess what I am trying to say here is that C# does not use C style shifts, so F# must make the same decision as generally, F# tries to behave similar to C#